# pandas dataframe slice with '_is_view=True' doesn't change original dataframe and '_is_view' stays True

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice

Could you someone please explain to me why I have the following result from this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.3, 1.3],[4, 6, 5.2],[43, 6.8, 55.2]])
df2 = df1.loc[1,0:] # 2nd row, all columns
print(df2._is_view) # True
print(df2._is_copy) # None
df2.iloc[1] = 999 # It changes df2 without warnings but df1 stays unchanged
print(df2._is_view) # Still True
```

From what I understand, the line `df2.iloc[1] = 999` should change `df1` as well.

Note that, if I select the second column, all rows (instead of 2nd row, all columns), the code works as "expected" (that is, df1 gets modified):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.3, 1.3],[4, 6, 5.2],[43, 6.8, 55.2]])
df2 = df1.loc[0:,1] # 2nd column, all rows.
print(df2._is_view) # True
print(df2._is_copy) # None
df2.iloc[1] = 999   # It DOES changes df1 as well ! 
print(df2._is_view) # Still True
```

Thank you people !

I tried the code above and I still cannot understand what's going on.
(pandas version: '2.0.2', python version 3.11.4)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, and I could be wrong, a pandas DataFrame is an object that is a collection of pandas Series, a pandas Series is defined as a column and not as a row.

Is a bit hard to know without checking the internals of pandas, but what i can imagine is that extracting a row will allocate a new object in memory while extracting a column will reuse the existing Series that lives into the dataFrame.

You can check this statement running a couple of times:

```
id(df1[1])  # no new id is generated, is just the internal Series
```

Interestingly enough that is not the case when you run:

```
id(df1.loc[0:,1])
id(df1.loc[1,0:])
```

As using this notation is allocating a new address in memory, probably cause is considering that you are making a iteration over the Series, and in the row case cause there was no object containing the row, so it needs to iterate.

So for me there is some internal check in the setter of the series that we are not seeing, that ensures that when you modify the Series it changes, but when you change a random series that you just created by iterating a row, it doesn't.

In any case everything is more natural when calling the columns in the usual way, so i guess this may not be the final answer for the case using loc.

In any case remember that "_is_view" and "_is_copy" don´t belong to the public API of pandas (they are internal implementations, as anything starting with _ ) and are not meant to be use by the final user. (they could be misleading)